# How to use WebDriverRunner to create a Chrome browser in incognito mode

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenide

I'm looking for an option to open chrome in INCOGNITO for my automation tests using SelenIDE/JUNIT/Maven.

I'm not really sure what kind of information I need to give here. I'll add a copy of our LocalTest page, which steers the WebdriverRunner.

I call the actual Url in the test class itself, because the site has different starting points to be tested.

this is how i'm callling the Url:

```
@Before
public void OpenCarUrl(){WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().get("MyUrl");}
```

I hope this is plenty but if I need to provide more information I'm always on the ready to answer.

the copy of our LocalTest

```
public class LocalTest extends SelenideHelperClass {

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LocalTest.class);


private static boolean osIs(String os) {
    return System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains(os);
}


@BeforeClass
public static void setupDriver() {
    if (System.getProperty("CHROMEDRIVER_HOME") != null) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("CHROMEDRIVER_HOME") + "/chromedriver");
    } else if (System.getenv("CHROMEDRIVER_HOME") != null) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getenv("CHROMEDRIVER_HOME") + "/chromedriver");
    } else {
        String driver;
        if (osIs("mac")) {
            driver = "chromedriver-mac";
        } else if (osIs("windows")) {
            driver = "chromedriver.exe";
        } else if (osIs("linux")) {
            driver = "chromedriver-linux";
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("OS could not be determined, chromedriver cannot be set or is unavailable");
        }
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/chromedriver/" + driver);
    }

    System.setProperty("selenide.browser", "Chrome");
    logger.info("Set selenide.browser to Chrome");
    logger.info("Set webdriver.chrome.driver to " + System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"));

    // ----------------


}

@AfterClass
public static void closeDriver() {
WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().quit();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution:

```
...
 } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("OS could not be determined, chromedriver cannot be set or is unavailable");
            }


            ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
            option.addArguments("start-maximized");
            option.addArguments("incognito");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/chromedriver/" + driver);

            ChromeDriver webdriver = new ChromeDriver(option);
            WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(webdriver);


        }

        System.setProperty("selenide.browser", "Chrome");
        logger.info("Set selenide.browser to Chrome");
        logger.info("Set webdriver.chrome.driver to " + System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"));
    }

....
```